# Button with BOTH color and background image

Tags: android, xml, button, background, background-image

Is there any way to set the color *and* background image for a button? I want a green button with a transparent .png but it seems you can only have one or the other.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(Don't) Use an ImageView

Set your set your green button background image as the background, and your transparent png as the src. You can apply a selector to the background just the same as you would to a button also...

**EDIT:** Actually there is an [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) already made for this, you should be using that instead. Slipped my mind.

Comment: Thanks, I was using `Button` instead of `ImageButton`. It works now. I'm now using `ImageButton` with `android:background` for the color and `android:src` for the image.

Answer (score 4):

Try This piece of code it works for me :)

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/button5"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
...
android:src="@drawable/settingbtn"
android:background="@drawable/red_color"
     />
```

Answer (score 1):

Draw separate images with the transparency and save the image. To show different images for the instances of the image being pressed,focused etc.. use the following method.

Use the image button with the background as the xml shown below:

```
 `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/imagewhenpressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
 <item android:state_focused="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/imagewhenfocused" /> <!-- focused -->
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/defaultimage" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>`
```

**Note:** Here the three images -imagewhenpressed.png,imagewhenfocused.png & defaultimage.png and this xml should be placed in the drawable directory. The ImageButton background should be assigned to the `filename` of this xml like `android:background="@drawable/xmlfilename"`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ImageButton` instead.

You can set a background like normal and in the `src` property you can select an image.
You can also mess with the `scaleType` property if the image gets too small or too big.